# Check how many days have passed

Tags: php, javascript

How can i write this correctly ? 
I want to check how many days have passed from publish_end day since the publish_start day and when they are more than 30 days then a message will be display.

```
var a = new Date("<?php echo $this->item->publish_start; ?>");
var b = a.getDate();

var c = new Date("<?php echo $this->item->publish_end; ?>");
var d = c.getDate();

var e =  d - b ;

    if( e > 30) {
        alert("<?php echo JText::_('You cant put more than 30 days'); ?>");
                return false;
     }
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could try the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin (comment not answer because it's not vanilla PHP and the OP said nothing about jQuery)

Comment: TImeago is for displaying.
I think the OP wants to make sure a "whatever" cannot be published for more than one month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getTime() function to get the millisecond difference:

```
if(d.getTime() - b.getTime() > 2592000000)
```

(30 days have 2 592 000 000 ms)

Comment: Where `b` and `d` are Date objects, yuo can just do `(d - b) > 2.592e9`.

Comment: Thats the answer!! I was trying 2 days to put this out...thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: Updated after clarification**

You'd be better off to find the difference between the dates in PHP, then pass that value to JavaScript.

I don't know what date formats those two variables are in, but if they're unix timestamps you could do this:

```
var e = <?php echo floor(strtotime($this->item->publish_end)-strtotime($this->item->publish_start))/86400); ?>
if( e > 30) {
    alert("<?php echo JText::_('You cant put more than 30 days'); ?>");
            return false;
}
```

Comment: If you have to transfer the 2 dates to the client JS anyways (for example to display them) doing it on the client side could be the better choice

Comment: it would help if you'd tell us what format $this->item->publish_end and $this->item->publish_start is in.

Comment: Start time: 2012-06-24 , End time: 2012-07-24

Answer (score 0):

Convert both a and c and convert them to epoch timestamps (seconds since jan 1, 1970, unix timestamps).  Take the difference of the two.  Divide the result by (60secs on a minute * 60 minutes in an hour * 24 hours in a day) then you have the difference in days.